# SVG foreignObject contents do not display unless plain text

Tags: html, svg, d3.js

I am trying to output HTML using the foreignObject tag inside an SVG drawing. I am using d3 to generate the elements. The only time the HTML content inside the foreignObject tag shows up is when the content inside the foreignObect tag is plain text, otherwise it just shows up as empty/blank. Please see this jsfiddle for an example of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/R9e3Y/29/

The contents inside the foreignObject tag show up on inspecting the element this this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">
    <foreignObject x="40" y="40" width="100" height="100">
        <div>test</div>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

but are not visible on the screen? How do I get the content to show up?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Since you're using d3 you need to tell d3 that the div is a html div and not some element in the svg namespace. Try

```
.append("xhtml:div")
```

Comment: do you know any workaround for ie 9 and ie10. Even after adding the above line, both browsers refuse to show the html content

Comment: Neither IE9 nor IE10 support the foreignObject tag I'm afraid

Comment: @RobertLongson you are right it's not working in IE , have any other solution that we can show it in IE because i have many inner element in foreignObject any help? u\my fiddle is here where i replace foreignObject with "xhtml:div"   in my last append of node http://jsfiddle.net/waamit14/HCF5W/

Comment: Bummer about IE9+, my gosh supporting IE is painful.  Thanks for the clue, Robert Longson.

Comment: One can also use the `.html` method and wrap text with a string `"<div>"` tag, but this is more correct.

Comment: Note also that `foreignObject` may require `width` and `height` values to be set, or they may default to `0` and result in everything being cropped away. That turned out be be my problem on mobile Safari; a comment on a related question linked to [this simple example](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2007/07/foreignobject-text.svg) which works on mobile and helped me troubleshoot.

Answer (score 19):

`<foreignObject>` allows embedding all kinds of markup, not just HTML. This means, there must be a way of determining what language is used. That's where namespaces come into play.

To tell SVG what kind of `foreignObject` you have, you have to put the content in the proper namespace.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">
  <foreignObject x="40" y="40" width="100" height="100">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">test</div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

In your example, the `<div>` element is in the SVG namespace, i.e. it's an SVG element, not an HTML one (albeit a non-standard one).

The `<foreignObject>` element also has a [`requiredExtensions`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#RequiredExtensionsAttribute) attribute to tell the browser which extension is used, however different browsers seem to be interpreting this attribute differently, so it's probably best to not set it.

Comment: Adding the requiredExtensions attribute didn't solve my problem in Safari iOS, but setting a height did.

Comment: when I edit your post with chrome dev tools and paste in this very code snippet instead, nothing is displayed.

Comment: @Blauhirn Updated the question.

Comment: `<foreignObject>` doesn't seem compatible with IE https://caniuse.com/?search=foreignobject

Comment: [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject#example) says: "In the context of SVG embedded in an HTML document, the XHTML namespace could be omitted, but it is mandatory in the context of an SVG document"

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you set `width` and `height` parameters.

Adding `xmlns` did not fix things for me. It turned out the problem for me was even more simple... I did not add `width` and `height` parameters, so content inside the `foreignObject` did not show, even though it was there. Both parameters seem to default to 0.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@robert-longson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13848804):

If you're using a `d3` [`selection.join()`](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join), it would look like this:

```js
myForeignObject.selectAll('div').data(myData).join('xhtml:div')
```

Note that the `xhtml` namespace is only specified in the `join()`, ***not*** in the `selectAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

I developed something for this. The code is below. A more advanced version uses a proxy to pull in external non-CORS resources. svg `foreignObject` blocks loading of any non-CORS cross-origin request. I wrote a simple proxy to run on Runkit. See at the bottom.

The limitations of this are: no external non-CORS fonts, no non-CORS images. Anyone who wants to help improve this, including adding in support for images and fonts, can contribute here: https://github.com/dosyago-coder-0/dompeg.js/blob/master/dompeg.js

*web page script:*

```
(async function (){ 
  const width = document.scrollingElement.scrollWidth;
  const height = document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight;
  const doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument('');
  doc.write(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
  doc.documentElement.setAttribute('xmlns', doc.documentElement.namespaceURI);

  const styles = [];
  for( let i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++ ) {
    const ss = document.styleSheets[i];
    if ( ss.cssRules ) {
      for( let j = 0; j < ss.cssRules.length; j++ ) {
         styles.push( ss.cssRules[j].cssText );
      }
    } else {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(ss.href);
        const cssText = await res.text();
        styles.push(cssText);
      } catch(e) {
          /** fetch to proxy here as fallback
           * uncomment if you set up your proxy server 
        try {
          const res = await fetch(`https://${YOUR PROXY SERVER}.runkit.sh/?url=${btoa(ss.href)}`);
          const cssText = await res.text();
          styles.push(cssText);
        } catch(e) { **/
          console.warn(`Exception adding styles from ${ss.href}`, e, e.stack);
        /** uncomment if you setup proxy  
        }  
        **/
      }
    }
  }


  Array.from( doc.querySelectorAll('noscript, link, script')).forEach( el => el.remove() );
  stripComments(doc);
  Array.from( doc.querySelectorAll('*[style]')).forEach( el => {
    const styleText = el.getAttribute('style');
    const uniq = (Math.random()+''+performance.now()).replace(/\./g,'x');
    const className = `class${uniq}`;
    const cssText = `.${className} {${ styleText }}`;
    styles.push( cssText );
    el.classList.add( className );
  });


  const styleElement = doc.createElement('style');
  styleElement.innerText = styles.join('\n');
  doc.documentElement.appendChild(styleElement);


  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  Object.assign( canvas, {width,height});
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const data = `
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="${width}" height="${height}">
    <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
     ${(new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(doc).slice(15)}
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>`;
  const DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

  const img = new Image();
  const svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml'});

  Object.assign( img, {width,height});  
  img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    const datauri = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    const anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.download = 'screen.jpg';
    anchor.href = datauri;
    anchor.target = "_new";
    anchor.innerText = 'download screen.jpg';
    anchor.addEventListener('click', e => {e.stopPropagation();anchor.remove();}, { capture: true });
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);
    Object.assign( anchor.style, {
      position: 'fixed',
      background:'white',
      fontSize: '18px',
      fontFamily: 'monospace',
      color: 'blue',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      zIndex: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
    });
  }
  img.src = buildSvgImageUrl(data);  
  img.style.position = "absolute";
  img.style.zIndex = "10000000";
  img.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  //document.body.appendChild(img);

  function buildSvgImageUrl(svg) {
    const b64 = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg)));
    return "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + b64;
  }

  function stripComments(docNode){
    const commentWalker = docNode.evaluate('//comment()', docNode, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    let comment = commentWalker.iterateNext();
    const cuts = [];

    while (comment) {
      cuts.push(comment);
      comment = commentWalker.iterateNext();
    }
    cuts.forEach( node => node.remove());
  }
}());
```

*runkit proxy server script:*

```
const request = require("request");
const rp = require('request-promise');
const {URL} = require('url');
const express = require("@runkit/runkit/express-endpoint/1.0.0");
const b64 = require('base-64');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const page = (url,err) => `
        <form method=POST style="
            position: fixed;
            position: sticky;
            display: table;
            top: 0px;
            z-index:12000000;
            background: white;">
            <label for=hider99>X</label><input id=hider99 type=checkbox>
            <style>
                #hider99:checked ~ fieldset {
                    display: none;
                }
            </style>
            <fieldset><legend>Proxy</legend>
            <p>
                <input required type=url size=62 name=url placeholder="any url" value="${url||'https://google.com/favicon.ico'}">
                <button style=background:lime>Load</button>
                ${ !! err ? `<p><span style=color:red>${err}</span>` : '' }           
            </fieldset>
        </form>`;
const app = express(module.exports);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get("/", async (req,res,next) => {
    console.log(req.query.url);
    let url;
    res.type('html');
    res.set('access-control-allow-origin', '*');
    try {
        url = b64.decode(req.query.url);
        new URL(url);
        } catch(e) { res.end(page('',"not a url"+e)); return; }
    try {
        res.type(type(url));
        const data = await rp(url);
        res.end(data);
        } catch(e) { res.end(page('',""+e)); }
});

app.get("/:anything", async (req,res,next) => {
    res.type('html');
    res.end('404 Not found');
});

function type(s = '') {
    return s.split(/\./g).pop() || 'html';
}
void 0;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var a = function(a) {
            var b = enter code heredocument.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "div");
            b.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + a + "</svg>";
            for (var c = document.createDocumentFragment(); b.firstChild.firstChild; ){
                c.appendChild(b.firstChild.firstChild);
            } 
            return c;
        }

        $('#app_canvasContainer svg').append(a('<foreignObject overflow="visible" width="200" height="100" x="'+ x +'"  y="'+ y +'" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><textarea class="text-entity" readonly="true" resizeable=false xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >'+ val +'</textarea>`enter code here`</foreignObject>'));
```