# HTML element inside SVG not displayed

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am struggeling with the `foreignObject` in SVG. I want to add text inside a `rect`, and to get auto text wrap I have chosen to use HTML. The description of `foreignObject` can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/extend.html#ForeignObjectElement).

I am working with D3, and this is my data:

```
var cds = [
{"uid":"U12","sid":"16","statement":"Movies","x":10,"y":10},
{"uid":"U20","sid":"17","statement":"Food","x":10,"y":170},
{"uid":"U22","sid":"15","statement":"Sport","x":10,"y":330}
];
```

I add a card for each datum and want to display the "statement" from the data.

```
var cardsize = { width : 150, height : 150 };

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 170)
    .attr("height", 490);

var card =  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(cds)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "card")
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) { 
        d.x = 10;
        d.y = 10+i*(10+cardsize.height);
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

card.append("svg:rect")
    .attr('width', cardsize.width)
    .attr('height', cardsize.height)

card.append("svg:foreignObject")
    .attr('width', cardsize.width)
    .attr('height', cardsize.height)
    .append('p')
    .attr("class","statement")
    .text(function(d) { return d.statement; });
```

The output of a card is this:

```
<g class="card" transform="translate(10,330)">
    <rect width="150" height="150"></rect>
    <foreignObject width="150" height="150"><
        p class="statement">Sport</p>
    </foreignObject>
</g>
```

I can't see the text in the (mac) browsers I have tested (Safari 6.0.2, Chrome 25.0.1364.99, Firefox 18.0.2). [W3's validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) doesn't like the output, and give me this error for each card:

> Element foreignObject not allowed as child of element g in this context.

So my question is, where is the problem, and why is foreignObject not allowed as a child of a `g` element?

I am also wondering why `.html(function(d) { return d.statement; });` doesn't work (no output). But `.text(function(d) { return d.statement; });` works fine?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EHzcR/1/).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848039/svg-foreignobject-contents-do-not-display-unless-plain-text

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Short answer

Specify the namespace in all tags in a foreignObject: replace `.append("p")` by `.append("xhtml:p")` and it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/EHzcR/2/

---

### Long answer

In the context of foreign objects, `<p></p>` is not recognized as a `xhtml` paragraph. Why? Simply because the namespace `xhtml` is not included in the `foreignObject` context (a `foreignObject` might contain anything (`xml` formated data for example) so it doesn't consider the input as html if you don't explicitly say it.).

So the `p` tag is considered as a custom tag, not as a `xhtml` tag. Thus, as the web browser doesn't recognize the tag `p` in the tags it knows, so it just doesn't interpret it and its content, even if it exists, it won't throw an error as well because this content might be totally valid, just not for its direct use.

It is fun to see that you always specify the namespace `svg` even if it is not necessary and how we all forget that the `p`, `div`... also have a very popular namespace.

The `selection.html()` function doesn't work because in its [implementation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/core/selection-html.js) it uses the `.innerHTML()` function of the element, but here, the foreignObject, not being an html element, doesn't have such a function.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your question whether or not you can actually view the text in the foreignObjects? (And if your answer is "yes", then what browser are you using?).

I'm looking forward to other answers here, because the method below does not seem optimal to me, but it does get most of the way there.

Using Chrome, and attempting to generate the `<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` tag inside the foreignObject as per the [W3C example](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/extend.html#ForeignObjectElement), and then the `<p>` inside the `<body>`, left the text unable to be seen for me. But then just leaving the inner `<body>` out, and adding a class to style the foreignObject, produced the desired result.

http://jsfiddle.net/6B4zs/5/

Updated portions of code added below:

**D3 section for adding foreignObject text**

```
svg.selectAll("foreignObject")
    .data(cds)
    .enter()
  .append("foreignObject")
    .attr("requiredFeatures", "http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility")
    .attr('width', cardsize.width)
    .attr('height', cardsize.height)
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", function (d, i) { return 10 + i * (10 + cardsize.height) })
    .attr("class", "fo-text")
    .text(function (d) { return d.statement; });
```

**CSS**

```
.fo-text {
    padding: 5px 10px;  
    font: 300 14px "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Matt. But you didn't add the `foreignObject` to the `g` object, which is a problem, because in my implementation I am dragging these cards around, so the text should be part of the `g.card` element (otherwise they will not tag along when the card is moved). I have updated the fiddle with dragging http://jsfiddle.net/E8PmE/. So I need a solution where I have `g.card` as parent, and then `rect` + `foreignObject` as children.

Comment: And to answer your question: I can't view the text in the `foreignObjects`, but when I inspect the elements, I can see that the text is in the DOM. I have also updated my question with browsers information.