# Implementing <div> tooltips via d3 within an <svg> container

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, d3.js, raphael

I'm relatively new to D3, svg, and javascript in general, so please bear with me :]

I have been experimenting with D3 for creating plots and graphs. I have created a small plot using D3 and have been attempting to make it compatible with IE8. Here is a link to the more-or-less working build of my graph.

http://jsfiddle.net/kingernest/YDQR4/1/

After some research, I quickly realized that the only way running D3 on IE8 would be at all feasible is by using other APIs in conjunction with D3. Luckily, I found that someone had already put in some work into a project called "r2d3" which, from my understanding, uses raphael to paint the canvas on the IE8 window instead of using SVG (which apparenly was not supported in IE8).

I have been able to get items drawn on the screen, which is half the battle. However, I'm having many issues, particularly with my tooltip. My tooltip is written as a DIV container that floats and changes position/opacity on hover of the data circles. This seems to work fine in other browsers, but with r2d3, I have not been able to get it working. I suspect this is because of the fact that I am creating the div tooltip outside of the  (in the #main div). However, I have tried placing tooltips inside of the SVG container with no avail. I then did more reseach and discovered I would have to wrap a div container inside a  tag, but after some experimentation with this, I still wasn't able to get the tooltip to work correctly in IE. I attempted to wrap the  in a SVG group (), and altered the positioning of this object instead, but this did not seem to work either, and simply through numerous exceptions when trying to append the foreignObject tag to a group.

At this point I'm sort of stuck, and was wondering if anyone had any suggestions as to how I may be able to successfully implement the tooltips. I've also noticed that using d3.select(this) inside my functions, when attempting to select a particular data point (in this case, a circle) seems to present a number of issues when attempting to access or modify that item's attributes, but I think this is a whole other issue entirely.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Example of how I'm currently creating the tooltips:

```
 //Create tooltip element
 var tooltip = d3.select("#main")
     .append("div")
         .attr("class", "tooltip")
     .style("position", "absolute")
     .style("z-index", "10")
     .style("opacity", 0);

function mousemove()
{    //Move tooltip to mouse location
    return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");                            
}

//Mouseover function for circles, displays shortened tooltip and causes other circles to become opaque
function mouseover()
{
    var myCircle = d3.select(this);

    d3.select(this).attr("class", "dataCircleSelected");    //Color circle green

    tooltip.html(    //Populate tooltip text
        "Username: " + d3.select(this).attr("username") + "<br/>" +
        "Session ID: " + d3.select(this).attr("sessionid") + "<br/>" + 
        "Impact CPU: " + d3.select(this).attr("impact")            
    )
    .transition()
    .duration(250)
    .style("opacity", .7);

    //After 1000ms, make other circle opaque
    svg.selectAll("circle")
    .filter(function(d, i){    //return every other circle
        return !d.compare(myCircle[0][0].__data__);
    })
    .transition().delay(1000)
    .style("opacity", .2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `foreignObjects` **AND** explicitly using the xhtml namespace for html tags in the `foreignObject` (write `xhtml:div` instead of `div`) as explained here: [HTML element inside SVG not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148481/html-element-inside-svg-not-displayed/15153990#15153990) ?

This would give something like that for the tooltip definition

```
 var tooltip = d3.select("#main").append("foreignObject")
     .append("xhtml:div")
         .attr("class", "tooltip")
     .style("position", "absolute")
     .style("z-index", "10")
     .style("opacity", 0);
```

Comment: If I append the tooltip to #main would this not mean that the foreignObject and toolTip would not be within the <svg> block, which I think will cause some problems for r2d3 when it comes to rendering the tooltip. Should I try appending it to my svg element instead?

Comment: Just tried both methods and I'm still not seeing a tooltip. I even moved my tooltip code to the bottom of the code to ensure that the circles or background wasn't being rendered over the tooltip.

Comment: @Burzum619 Having a decent tooltip using d3 is really hard and I find yours already great (using chrome). This "answer" was to be sure you tried it as I never had the pleasure to play with previous versions of IE or r2d3. I would recommend putting the tooltip in a fixed box above are bellow the graph if you can on IE 8 and previous. Otherwise, be sure I will save the answer which will solve your problem.

Comment: @Burzum619 you are right, the foreignObject should be within the svg block.

Comment: Perhaps I will try to use a rect instead of a div, although I'm not sure if I will be able to position it the same way I was doing before. I'll let you know if I have any luck!