# foreign-object content not appearing in plotly

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, plotly

I was trying to wrap html content into plotly chart to apply text-overflow to the tick labels by using foreignObject. All these implementations did it in **plotly_afterplot** event. But it's strange content is not appearing which is in foreignObject.

I tried following the suggestion, which is suggested by others.

[SVG foreignObject contents do not display unless plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848039/svg-foreignobject-contents-do-not-display-unless-plain-text)

https://github.com/MithrilJS/mithril.js/issues/752

DOM structure looks like below.

```
<g class="ytick">
  <foreignobject requiredextensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="150" height="150">
  <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <p width="100" height="200">DEF</p>
  </body>
 </foreignobject>
</g>
```

Comment: Tried how? please add a [mcve]